# SharedResource not found in .NetCore 6 MVC

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, localization

I am trying to do localication on .Net Core 6, MVC application. I could have done in view section, but I can not have a sharedResource.resx. so I did as following

in Startup , in ConfigureServices I added the following

```
  services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
  services.AddControllersWithViews()
     .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
       options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
     .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
      {
          options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
       });
```

then in Configure Method I added the following

```
 var supportedCulture = new List<CultureInfo>()
        {
            new CultureInfo("fa-IR"),
            new CultureInfo("en-US")
        };
        var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
        {
            SupportedCultures = supportedCulture,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCulture,
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fa-IR"),
            RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
            {
                new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
            }
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
```

Then I created the class File named "SharedResource" in Model folder of the application.
Then I created a folder named "Resources" on root level of the application.
Exactly under the Resources Folder I created two resource files. name   SharedResource.en-US  and SharedResource.fa-IR, with elements inside of them.

The I addedd these lines above the view

```
 @using System.Globalization
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
 @inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResource> SharedLocalizer
```

but when I want to have the value of   @SharedLocalizer["Year"] , it doesn't work and shows that it has not found the sharedresource

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

where is the my problem?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuG56.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class SharedResource class file should be exactly under the root directory. that solved the problem.